# How to read and understand the console log of Event-Parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I often don't exactly know which properties are included in the Parameters of click-events.
In my actual Job I'd like to know which cell was clicked inside an devExpress-Gridview (ASP.NET MVC Extension).
So I fired the Event and logged the Parameters to console:

```
function OnContext(s, e) {
console.log(s);
console.log(e);
}
```

With this I got hundrets of properties.
How can I Access e.g. the target-accessKey-Value of the log, attached as screenshot?
The screenshot is from `console.log(e);` - Parameter:
Object - htmlEvent - target - accessKey

This is only for Example so if someone could explain how to read this Output, I could solve such "Little" Problems better by myself :)

[image]

**UPDATE**
It really seems to be that simple:

```
const value = e.htmlEvent.target.value;
```

Didn`t recognize the htmlEvent before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want just to get a value of the input:
In your case it will be:

```
const value = e.htmlEvent.target.value;
```

and in any other case if you use javascript and you have some user events

For example, get value from the input

you should use

```
const value = event.target.value;
```

and in your case `htmlEvent` it is the action of the user

Comment: Ok, I found it. It should be `e.htmlEvent.target.value.`

Comment: if it helps you, please correct like right answer or, upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, you correct your answer, than I could vote for it.